# Selenium javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file

Tags: selenium

I am facing this error for my Selenium script...

I am trying to generate the pdf evidence of the testing i am doing and while running my script i am getting this error

My Code:

```
package test;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;    
import org.testng.annotations.Test;   
import com.googlecode.seleniumjavaevidence.report.GenerateEvidenceReport;  
import com.googlecode.seleniumjavaevidence.selenium.SeleniumEvidence;  
import java.util.List;   
import org.openqa.selenium.By;   
import org.openqa.selenium.OutputType;   
import org.openqa.selenium.TakesScreenshot;   
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;   
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.*;  

public class NewTest  {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    List<SeleniumEvidence> evidence ;
    String exception ; 

    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws Exception {  
       driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");  
    }   

    @Test  
    public void testLogin() throws Exception {  
        try {  
             // driver.findElement(By.id("lst-ib"));   
            evidence.add(new SeleniumEvidence("get evidence from here",((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64)));  
         } catch (Exception e) {
            evidence.add(new SeleniumEvidence("Unexpected error", ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BASE64)));      
             exception = e.fillInStackTrace().getMessage();          
         } finally {                
             GenerateEvidenceReport.generatePDFEvidence(evidence, "null", null, null, exception);   
         }   
     }  
}
```

Comment: Is there more of the error message you can display?

Answer (score 0):

https://code.google.com/p/selenium-java-evidence/wiki/HowToUse?wl=pt-BR 
Seems to suggest:

> A imageio.IOException will always appears if you don't put the images
>   in the correct path on your code. It's not a problem from
>   selenium-java-evidence... Revise your code and put all images in the
>   correct path.